# Eclipse doesn't identify my project as Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I import a project from the SVN, which is a Java project.

When I open one of it class, for example, I can't use open declaration\open implementation\ open return type, and so on..

It just show me the class as a text file. How can I fix it?

Comment: is it a maven project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `project->properties->facets->java` and enable the java facet

Alternatively you can open the `.project` file and add the java nature eclipse is adding for new java projects:

```
<projectDescription>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```